# Ubuntu 12.04 wireless does not detect networks

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, dual-boot, macbook-pro

I installed Ubuntu on a partition of my MacBook Pro. Wireless connections work fine when I switch to OSX, but the wireless networks are not even detected when I boot Ubuntu. I installed Wicd as a new network manager, but I'm still having the same problem. Ubuntu works on a wired connection though.

I have searched the web for a solution... similar questions have been asked but I have not been able to find a way to fix this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try hooking your computer up to Ethernet and checking additional drivers or jockey? Just search for jockey in the dash and it will come up.

Answer (score 1):

Check if it is blocked by hardware of software:

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

Sample session:

```
sk@ubuntu:~$ sudo rfkill list all
0: wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
sk@ubuntu:~$ sudo rfkill unblock all
sk@ubuntu:~$ sudo rfkill list all
0: wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have a problem (of any kind) I fist visit the comprehensive [Ubuntu community wiki !](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/)

Here is a very good [Wireless troubleshooting guide.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide)